# how to rebalance cassandra cluster after adding new node

Tags: cassandra

I had a 3 node cassandra cluster with replication factor of 2. The nodes were running either dsc1.2.3 or dsc1.2.4. Each node had num_token value of 256 and initial_token was commented. This 3 node cluster was perfectly balanced i.e. each owned around 30% of the data.

One of the nodes crashed so I started a new node and nodetool removed the node that had crashed. The new node got added to the cluster but the two older nodes have most of the data now (47.0% and 52.3%) and the new node has just 0.7% of the data.

The output of nodetool status is

```
Datacenter: xx-xxxx
===================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address           Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
UN  10.xxx.xxx.xxx    649.78 MB  256     47.0%  ba3534b3-3d9f-4db7-844d-39a8f98618f1  1c
UN  10.xxx.xxx.xxx    643.11 MB  256     52.3%  562f7c3f-986a-4ba6-bfda-22a10e384960  1a
UN  10.xxx.xxx.xxx    6.84 MB    256     0.7%   5ba6aff7-79d2-4d62-b5b0-c5c67f1e1791  1c
```

How do i balance this cluster?

Comment: Can you include the output of 'nodetool status'?

Comment: Did you start the new node with num_tokens = 256 too?

Comment: Edited the post to added output of 'nodetool status'

Comment: Are you sure you didn't start the new node with num_tokens = 1, then set num_tokens = 256, then restart it?  That could explain what you are seeing.

Comment: I changed all properties in cassandra.yaml (cluster name, num_tokens, initial_token, seed, etc.), saved the file and then restarted cassandra.

Comment: I can't quite explain what you have seen, but it is important to set these properties *before* starting Cassandra for the first time. I suggest you decommission the new node, completely wipe its data and commit log directories, then bootstrap it back in.

Answer (score 6):

You didn't mention running a repair on the new node, if indeed you haven't yet done that it's likely the cause of your lack of data on the new node.

Until you run a nodetool repair the new node will only hold the new data that gets written to it or the data that read-repair pulls in. With vnodes you generally shouldn't need to re-balance, if I'm understanding vnodes correctly, but I haven't personally yet moved to using vnodes so I may be wrong about that.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like your new node hasn't bootstrapped. Did you add `auto_bootstrap=true` to your cassandra.yaml?

If you don't want to bootstrap, you can run `nodetool repair` on the new node and then `nodetool cleanup` on the two others until the distribution is fair.