# Cassandra : data not replicated on new node

Tags: cassandra, replication

I added a new node to my cassandra cluster (the new node is not a seed node). I now have 3 nodes on my cluster :

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address       Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               
Rack

UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  52.25 GB   256          100.0%            XXX  rack1

UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  63.65 GB   256          100.0%            XXX  rack1

UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  314.72 MB  256          100.0%            XXX  rack1
```

I have a replication factor of 3 :

```
DESCRIBE KEYSPACE mykeyspace

CREATE KEYSPACE mykeyspace WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1': '3'}  AND durable_writes = true;
```

but the data is not replicated on the new cluster (node with 314 MB of data).

I tried to use nodetool rebuild :

> ERROR [STREAM-IN-/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 2016-11-11 08:28:42,765
>   StreamSession.java:520 - [Stream
>   #0e7a0580-a81b-11e6-9a1c-6d75503d5d02] Streaming error occurred java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type 0 at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage$Type.get(StreamMessage.java:97)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.messages.StreamMessage.deserialize(StreamMessage.java:58)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:261)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_74] ERROR [Thread-16]
>   2016-11-11 08:28:42,765 CassandraDaemon.java:195 - Exception in thread
>   Thread[Thread-16,5,RMI Runtime] java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException at
>   com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:32)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_74] Caused by:
>   java.lang.InterruptedException: null at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.reportInterruptAfterWait(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2014)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74] at
>   java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2048)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74] at
>   java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue.put(ArrayBlockingQueue.java:353)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_74] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.compress.CompressedInputStream$Reader.runMayThrow(CompressedInputStream.java:184)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] ... 1 common frames omitted INFO 
>   [STREAM-IN-/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 2016-11-11 08:28:42,805
>   StreamResultFuture.java:182 - [Stream
>   #0e7a0580-a81b-11e6-9a1c-6d75503d5d02] Session with /XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is complete WARN  [STREAM-IN-/XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] 2016-11-11 08:28:42,807
>   StreamResultFuture.java:209 - [Stream
>   #0e7a0580-a81b-11e6-9a1c-6d75503d5d02] Stream failed ERROR [RMI TCP Connection(14)-127.0.0.1] 2016-11-11 08:28:42,808
>   StorageService.java:1128 - Error while rebuilding node
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamException: Stream failed at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.management.StreamEventJMXNotifier.onFailure(StreamEventJMXNotifier.java:85)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$6.run(Futures.java:1310)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:457)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.executeListener(ExecutionList.java:156)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionList.execute(ExecutionList.java:145)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:202)
>   ~[guava-18.0.jar:na] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.maybeComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:210)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamResultFuture.handleSessionComplete(StreamResultFuture.java:186)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.closeSession(StreamSession.java:430)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.StreamSession.onError(StreamSession.java:525)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   org.apache.cassandra.streaming.ConnectionHandler$IncomingMessageHandler.run(ConnectionHandler.java:279)
>   ~[apache-cassandra-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1] at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_74]

I also tried to change the option but the data is still not copied to the new node :
auto_bootstrap: true

Could you please help me understand why the data is not replicated on the new node ?

Please let me know if you need further information from my configuration.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16343142/how-to-rebalance-cassandra-cluster-after-adding-new-node first- if the answers there don't apply we can dig deeper.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help. I actually read this question first. I have the same num_tokens on the 3 nodes (same hardware config). I added `auto_bootstrap=true` in the cassandra config. I ran  `nodetool repair`  on the new node  , `nodetool cleanup` on the other nodes but the data would not be replicated on the new node.

Answer (score 0):

It appears (from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10448) that this is due to [CASSANDRA-10961](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-10961). Applying that fix should address it.

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.1.1. Am I affected by the bug ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Seems like you are. Sure looks the same.

Comment: I have installed Cassandra 3.0.9 on the new node. I did not notice an improvement. I have not yet updated the other nodes, it will take a few days before I can update Cassandra on the other nodes. I will let you know if that fixes the issue. Thanks

Comment: Hi Chris, I installed Cassandra 3.0.9 on my cluster but I still do not have a copy of the data on my new node. I ran a nodetool repair but nothing changed : UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  52.47 GB   256          100.0%            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1
UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  63.92 GB   256          100.0%            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1
UN  XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX  462.97 MB  256          100.0%            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx  rack1

Comment: I don't think it is a matter of just installing a new version (though it does look like this is fixed in 3.3). For the older versions you need to use the patched jar linked on the bug report page.

Comment: Hello Chris, You are right I could have just used the patched jar. This issue was fixed in 3.0.3, I am using 3.0.9. I do not have any of the error messages in the log files but most of the data is not copied to the new node (only a tiny fraction). I ran nodetool repair on my 3 nodes, no error messages on the log files. Any suggestions ?